# How to communicate between WCF service and host application?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service, host

I created an WCF service through this [tutorial](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2010/06/16/wcf-simple-example-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx). This works great, no problems here.
Now I am hosting the service in an Managed Application. But at the same time I would like to used the input from the client to the service in the host application.

I don't need Duplex communication between the Client and the Service. I just need communication between the Service and the Host communication.

What would be the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve it using the information from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139809/sending-messages-to-wcf-host-process). In which it was pointed out that service classes can also be passed to the host. Then it is as simple as adding an event listener which responds to events from the Service.

Comment: In such case your service will be singleton.

Answer (score 2):

It is like communication between threads. You need some shared variable with proper locking / synchronization. Your host application will write to this variable and your service will be able to read from that variable.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Okay, I could see this working. But how do I access variables part of the service object from the host application or vice-versa? I don't have a reference to the service since I use the Host.open() command to host the service.

Comment: You do not access variables in service instance. Your variables has to be shared by wellknown object. For example you can imlement singleton which will expose such variables to both service and host. Other approach is using service locator for shared object.

Comment: Do you mean I have to create a separate object with singleton properties in the Host application. How can I create a reference to this object from my Service? My ultimate goal is to trigger a function in the host application, when the WCF service receives data from the client, would this work using the singleton method?

Answer (score 2):

There is a framework and tutorial available that seems to handle this problem quite nicely [WPF Service Host on Codeplex](http://wpfservicehost.codeplex.com/).

EDIT: Updated to illustrate technique created by the WPF Service Host template.

The WPF Service Host is a template for Visual Studio that creates a skeleton application and test client. I'll describe the relevant pieces here.

Here's what the skeleton project looks like:

[image: Skeleton Project]

ClientServiceHost.cs

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WPFServiceHost1.Service
{
    public class ClientServiceHost : IDisposable
    {
        private bool _Initalized;

        private ServiceHost _InnerServiceHost;
        private MainWindow _MainWindow;

        public ClientServiceHost(MainWindow mainWindow)
        {
            _MainWindow = mainWindow;
            InitializeServiceHost();
        }

        private void InitializeServiceHost()
        {
            try
            {
                ClientService clientService = new ClientService(_MainWindow);
                _InnerServiceHost = new ServiceHost(clientService);

                _InnerServiceHost.Opened += new EventHandler(_InnerServiceHost_Opened);
                _InnerServiceHost.Faulted += new EventHandler(_InnerServiceHost_Faulted);
                _InnerServiceHost.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to initialize ClientServiceHost", ex);
            }
        }

        void _InnerServiceHost_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _Initalized = true;
        }

        void _InnerServiceHost_Faulted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this._InnerServiceHost.Abort();

            if (_Initalized)
            {
                _Initalized = false;
                InitializeServiceHost();
            }
        }

        #region IDisposable Members

        public void Dispose()
        {
            try
            {
                _InnerServiceHost.Opened -= _InnerServiceHost_Opened;
                _InnerServiceHost.Faulted -= _InnerServiceHost_Faulted;
                _InnerServiceHost.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                try { _InnerServiceHost.Abort(); }
                catch { }
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WPFServiceHost1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="WPFServiceHost1" Height="344" Width="343" Closing="Window_Closing">
    <Grid>
        <Label Height="28" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="119">Messages received:</Label>
        <ListBox Margin="21,38,26,21" Name="listBox1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Threading;
using WPFServiceHost1.Service;

namespace WPFServiceHost1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public SynchronizationContext _SyncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        private ClientServiceHost _ClientServiceHost;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _ClientServiceHost = new ClientServiceHost(this);
        }

        private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            _ClientServiceHost.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

IClientService.cs

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WPFServiceHost1.Service
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "urn:WPFServiceHost")]
    public interface IClientService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void ClientNotification(string message);
    }
}
```

ClientService.cs

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WPFServiceHost1.Service
{
    [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
    public class ClientService : IClientService
    {
        private MainWindow _MainWindow;

        public ClientService(MainWindow window)
        {
            _MainWindow = window;
        }

        #region IClientService Members
        public void ClientNotification(string message)
        {
            try
            {
                _MainWindow._SyncContext.Send(state =>
                {
                    _MainWindow.listBox1.Items.Add(message);
                }, null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new FaultException(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ClientServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="ClientServiceBehavior"
                name="WPFServiceHost1.Service.ClientService">
                <endpoint address="ClientService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WPFServiceHost1.Service.IClientService"/>
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8010" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And the TestClient, Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IClientService proxy = null;

            try
            {
                proxy = ChannelFactory<IClientService>.CreateChannel(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8010/ClientService"));
                Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> when ClientService is running.");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Sending a single message to ClientService");
                proxy.ClientNotification("Hello from TestClient");

                Console.WriteLine();

                Console.Write("Enter a valid number to load test ClientService: ");
                string result = Console.ReadLine();
                int testCount = Convert.ToInt32(result);
                int counter = 0;
                object counterLock = new object();

                while (true)
                {
                    lock (counterLock)
                    {
                        Thread t = new Thread(() => proxy.ClientNotification(string.Format("Load test from TestClient: {0}", ++counter)));
                        t.Start();
                    }

                    if (counter == testCount)
                        break;
                }

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            finally
            {
                ICommunicationObject co = proxy as ICommunicationObject;
                try
                {
                    co.Close();
                }
                catch { co.Abort(); }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```