# How to acces a Service from the Service host in WCF Communication

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdualhttpbinding

I have a number of clients, communicating using WCF wsDualHttpBinding, that are accessing a host, asking for information.
This information has be to searched, this means that the answer is can not be given back in the same thread.

The problem looks the same as in:
[How to communicate between WCF service and host application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679946/how-to-communicate-between-wcf-service-and-host-application)

Only I can not use the Singleton constructor but have to use the Typeof(..) contructor of the host because I can have more clients.
But how can the service host access the client to send the correct answer?

Regards,

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that the out-of-the box WCF duplex communication can not work?

Here's a definition and example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx

Comment: Yes, all examples I found use the solution that they immediately send an answer back to the server. But in my situation the host passes the message to an other thread to find the answer for the client, and when this thread returns the answer, the host has to start the callback to the client. But how does this host access the service that is initiating the question?