# Communication Between WCF Rest Service and host application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I have a WCF Rest web service that I am hosting in a managed application.  What I would like is for client input to the service to be passed to the host application for processing, and the results are then passed back to the client.  From similar questions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679946/how-to-communicate-between-wcf-service-and-host-application) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139809/sending-messages-to-wcf-host-process) I know I can use events to pass the data from the service to my host application.  However, I cannot seem to figure out how to get the resulting data passed back to the client.  Is there a way to do this using the webOperationContext or perhaps by creating another event in the host application to pass the data back to the web service?

Comment: Can I ask, what is the client written in?  I may be able to help you on this.

Comment: The client is written in C#, on the .net 4.0 framework

Comment: Is the WCF processing quick?  If so then just pass the result back to the client as an out parameter or the result of your WCF method.