# Firing event from WCF service with custom EventArgs - Circular Reference(?)

Tags: c#, wcf, events, circular-reference

I've created WCF service along this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6L86eqUK_qs&t=7s). I'm hosting this service via windows forms application. I've done event setting like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139809/sending-messages-to-wcf-host-process). Simply I'm firing an event from service and handling it in my WF host application. After that i wanted to pass a value from the event handler so i used class which inherits from `EventArgs` and have additional properties. I set them in the event handler. The first answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446256/pass-a-return-value-back-through-an-eventhandler?fbclid=IwAR0oNMme7ntOomK1C_s0ONkOCzE1H0Z840Q-GTkKMiMdVAb5kcIWvzbVaAc) 
led to that, but... I assume that i can have multiple properties and set them in the event handler - and after firing the event read them - if so, I want to have more than one property. If I wanted only 1 return value i could use the second answer from last linked question. And now i must have a class which inherits from `EventArgs` and adds additional properties, the problem is that i have to access it from host and service project and this is a circular reference, I've tried with interface but interface cannot inherit from `EventArgs`. And I have warning that types might be not compatible.

To sum up:

1. Can I set multiple properties of the class which inherit from `EventArgs` in the event handler, and read them in the caller? (I'm pretty sure that I can, but is it a bad practise?)
2. How to solve this reference problem? (I read about interfaces, but I think this is not a case here)

Comment: When we analyze it, `EventArgs` really has nothing to do with it. After all, suppose your event had arguments that *didn't* inherit from `EventArgs`. Wouldn't the problem be exactly the same? (Side point - is there actually any need to inherit from `EventArgs`?) One way to avoid a circular reference is to move a class to a third project which is referenced from the other two. It's hard to say more than that without seeing some concrete details.

Comment: A lot of event accept a state object so if you have multiple properties to change pass a state object.  A state object class is passed by reference so if the event changes value the original object contains same new value.  See one of the asynchronous Socket examples at msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples

Comment: Hmmm... So the arguments sent like: 'public void OnSomethig(Object sender, EventArgs e, ref int x, ref int xx...)' wont be considered like bad practise? I thought that EventArgs is the object to pass some additional arguments.

Comment: So I got the clue that It's not a good idea to add the third project only for one class which inherits from EventArgs. I will edit or answer the question, when I solve my problem. I think I should dig more about how to return or pass and change values of objects via event handler.